# Gmail or Inbox not loading mails

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

I'm using gmail and inbox in my browser, they just work fine. However, on Android the Gmail app or Inbox app both displays nothing left whereas I *do* have emails in my inbox. If I try to switch in other categories such as spams or trash, it displays "No network" even though I'm connected.

I have a rooted phone with JB 4.2.2 (deodexed) and:

- Xposed
- Greenify Pro
- GravityBox
- Xprivacy (not for system apps)
- ...
- I removed some system apps using ROM Toolbox but only samsung's bloat

I tried:

- turning off Greenify auto-hibernate and Xprivacy for inbox
- deleting data of Gmail, Inbox, or Google Play Services. When I try to use Inbox it now asks me to connect and then says that an error occured and try again later.
- download manager is not disabled
- removed /system/etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn sync `on`. Go to your notification toggle section, and there should be a loop, that is the sync toggle button

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked :'(

Comment: Try going to Accounts, then go to google... sign out of your google account, then sign back in. It will refresh all of your google settings... and try disabling XPosed for some time

Answer (score 0):

I would try to uninstal and reinstall app and login to see if your same settings are still applied. If so. Login from a pc and make changes that way. Always make sure you log in and out each time.